# Rearrange order or elements in each row of a multidimensional array based on another array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have an array of associative arrays and the keys within each row are not in the order that I'd like them.  How can I adjust all rows to have their associative keys in a pre-defined order?

My input array:

```
$array = [
    [
        'FirstName' => 'Robin',
        'Address' => 'Cave',
        'LastName' => 'Mactimmy',
        'Tel' => '9076',
        'Email' => 'i@o.com',
    ],
    [
        'Address' => 'uytr',
        'FirstName' => 'Bill',
        'Email' => 'j@k.com',
        'LastName' => 'Gates',
        'Tel' => '7654',
    ],
    [
        'LastName' => 'Mahoney',
        'Email' => 'y@i.ie',
        'FirstName' => 'Tom',
        'Tel' => '5689',
        'Address' => 'kklll',
    ]
];
```

My preferred order is `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `Tel`, `Email` and I have these values stored in an array.

I have tried `ksort()` and `usort()`, but with my code the array ordering does not seem to be updating.

My desired result:

```
[
    [
        'FirstName' => 'Robin',
        'LastName' => 'Mactimmy',
        'Address' => 'Cave',
        'Tel' => '9076',
        'Email' => 'i@o.com',
    ],
    [
        'FirstName' => 'Bill',
        'LastName' => 'Gates',
        'Address' => 'uytr',
        'Tel' => '7654',
        'Email' => 'j@k.com',
    ],
    [
        'FirstName' => 'Tom',
        'LastName' => 'Mahoney',
        'Address' => 'kklll',
        'Tel' => '5689',
        'Email' => 'y@i.ie',
    ]
]
```

Comment: You said you tried to use ksort, but ksort won't sort like you want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic on your data:

```
$array = [
    0 => Array
        (
            'FirstName' => 'Robin',
            'Address' => 'Cave',
            'LastName' => 'Mactimmy',
            'Tel' => '9076',
            'Email' => 'i@o.com',
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'Address' => 'uytr',
            'FirstName' => 'Bill',
            'Email' => 'j@k.com',
            'LastName' => 'Gates',
            'Tel' => '7654',
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'LastName' => 'Mahoney',
            'Email' => 'y@i.ie',
            'FirstName' => 'Tom',
            'Tel' => '5689',
            'Address' => 'kklll',
        )
];
```

I think it is good solution:

```
<?php

$order = [ 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Address', 'Tel', 'Email'];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $sortable) {
    $result[] = array_merge(array_flip($order), $sortable);
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This was the first one to work for me and it seems the most straight forward to me. The array_map one above is also a nice take on this method but I prefer the explicitness of this one in this case. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Flipping inside the loop is not best practice / best performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map` in conjunction with `array_merge`. Something like this:

```
$result = array_map(
    function ($arr) use($sample) { return array_merge($sample, $arr); },
    $array
);
```

Here I assume that `$array` is object array and `$sample` is array with correct ordered keys.

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom key sorter:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    // Custom key sort
}

uksort($array, "cmp");
```

or using recursive ksort:

```
ksortRecursive(&$array, $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR) {
    if (!is_array($array)) return false;
    ksort($array, $sort_flags);
    foreach ($array as &$arr) {
        ksortRecursive($arr, $sort_flags);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Borrowed from: https://gist.github.com/cdzombak/601849

Answer (score 1):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $order = array('FirstName' => 0, 'LastName' => 1, 'Address' => 2, 'Tel' => 3, 'Email' => 4);
    if ($a == $b || !isset($order[$a]) || !isset($order[$b])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($order[$a] < $order[$b]) ? -1 : 1;
}

uksort($a, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function customArraySort($array, $exampleArray) {
  $returnArray = array();
    foreach($array as $arrIndex => $arrSubArr) {
      $returnArray[$arrIndex] = array();
        foreach($exampleArray as $exArIndex => $value)
          $returnArray[$arrIndex][$exArIndex] = $arrSubArr[$exArIndex];
    }
  return $returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_walk()` is a great tool for this task because it allows you to pass in an array to be used on each iteration.

Modify each row by reference and overwrite each row with the product of `array_merge()` which honors the desired keys while retaining the original values.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aXjtH))

```
array_walk(
    $array,
    fn(&$row, $index, $order) => $row = array_merge($order, $row),
    array_flip(['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Address', 'Tel', 'Email'])
);
var_export($array);
```

---

From PHP7.4, arrow function syntax eliminates the need to call `use()` to invite globally scoped data inside the custom function scope.  `array_map()` returns the new array instead of modifying the original.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ek4h))

```
$order = array_flip(['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Address', 'Tel', 'Email']);
var_export(
    array_map(fn($row) => array_merge($order, $row), $array)
);
```

---

For the record, because the arrays being used are associative, `array_replace()` can be used instead of `array_merge()` with the same effect.